# Gson custom error handling

Tags: android, gson

I'm trying to use the [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library to parse some json data. The response from the server could be either of these:

success result:

```
{myObject: {foo:"1", bar:"bleh"}}
```

fault result:

```
{error: {message:"invalid token", code:320} }
```

It seems like Gson can only handle a single return type, such as something like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject object = gson.fromJson(value, MyObject.class);
```

How can I properly parse the data/(error) from the feed using the Gson and not just flat out JSON parsing myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Brian. I ended up just parsing like this

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    parser.parse(value).getAsJsonObject();
```

and then checking if the error node was present so I could throw the server exception. If the node wasn't present, then I used Gson from there.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    ArrayList<GridItemVo> list = gson.fromJson(value, new TypeToken<ArrayList<GridItemVo>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't know what you're going to be getting it's really hard to use something like Gson and deserialize to a POJO. You're actually getting an object with either a "myObject" or "error" field. One approach is to simply create a comprehensive object. Gson sets any fields not present to `null` when parsing the JSON so something like this would work fine:

```
class JSONResponse {
    private MyObject myObject;
    private Error error;

    static class MyObject {
        String foo;
        String bar;
    }

    static class Error {
        String message;
        int code;
    }

    public boolean isError() {
        return error != null;
    }

    // Getters that access the fields of the objects
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks! that's a pretty good solution. I ended up checking for the error manually in the json.

Comment: if i receive array of MyObject is it work? i worry static cause all object have same value